# No more than one executeBatch can be called from within a testmethod

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

How to fix below error message in test class

```
            System.UnexpectedException: No more than one executeBatch can be called from within a test method.  Please make sure the iterable returned from your start method matches the batch size, resulting in one executeBatch invocation.
```

Please note already tried adding Limit 200 as suggested here https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000330685&type=1&mode=1 but no success

My apex class is

```
            global class ERTExtract255BatchClass implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
                global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
                    return Database.getQueryLocator(
                'SELECT ID,Description,Case_Desc_255__c FROM Case' 
                    );
                }
                global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Case> scope){
                // process each batch of record
                List<Case> lstCase = new List<Case>();       
                for (Case cas : scope) {
                string Strdesc = cas.Description ; 
            if(Strdesc.length()>255){
                cas.Case_Desc_255__c = cas.Description.Left(255);
                lstCase.add(cas);  
            }
                }   
            update lstCase;
            }   
            global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){

            }   
 
            }
```

My test class is

```
            @isTest(SeeAllData=false)
            public class testERTExtract255BatchClass {

            @IsTest
            static void testBatchJob(){
              
               List<Case> cases = new List<Case>();
               for (integer i =0;i<300;i++)
               {
                    Case c = new Case();
                    c.Description = 'aaaaaa'.rightPad(255,'b');
                    c.status = 'new';
                    c.Subject = 'test';
                    //add other mandatory fields 
                    cases.add(c);
                }

                insert cases;

                Test.startTest();
                Database.executeBatch(new ERTExtract255BatchClass());
                Test.stopTest();


                Case Strcase = [Select id,Case_Desc_255__c from Case];
                System.assertEquals(Strcase.Case_Desc_255__c.length(),255);

                    }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any special reason why you need `for (integer i =0;i<300;i++)`?
If you'd make 200 or less it should fit in nicely into "1 execute() call in unit test".

Or what you can do is to pass an optional parameter to [`Database.executeBatch`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm) method. (in that documentation you can see the default is 200). So if you go `Database.executeBatch(new ERTExtract255BatchClass(), cases.size());` it should be fine.